# Cleanup steps for Cucumber scenarios

Tags: cucumber

Is there a way to define the cleanup steps for all of the scenarios for a feature in Cucumber? I know that `Background` is used to define the setup steps for each scenario that follows it, but is there a way to define something like that to happen at the end of each scenario?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an After [hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) that will run after each scenario:

```
After do
  ## teardown code
end
```

There's also a Before hook that will allow you to set up state and/or test data prior to the scenario:

```
Before do
  ## setup code
end
```

The Before and After hooks provide the functionality of `setup` and `teardown` from `Test::Unit`, and they are generally located in `hooks.rb` in the `features/support` directory.

Comment: Updating hooks doc URL: [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/support_files/hooks.md)

Answer (score 18):

should also notice that 'Before' and 'After' is global hooks i.e those hooks are run for every scenario in your features file

If you want the setup and teardown to be run for just few testcases ( grouped by tags) then you need to use taggedHooks, where the syntax is

```
Before('@cucumis, @sativus') do
# This will only run before scenarios tagged
# with @cucumis OR @sativus.
end


AfterStep('@cucumis', '@sativus') do
# This will only run after steps within scenarios tagged
# with @cucumis AND @sativus.
end
```

For more info : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a clean up before or after all the scenarios in a feature (i.e not after every scenario in a feature) , you can work around it by defining a scenario at the start of your feature file that does the clean up.

```
    @clean_database
  Scenario: Clean the database before running any tests.
    Given Clean the db first
```

In your stepDef for "Clean the db first" you can do a clean up of your db and will be run only once for the whole feature file instead of after every scenario.

Using
`@Before or @After` will only clean up after every scenario and that may not be something you want.