# Ruby Cucumber - Add Ruby codes

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How do I add Ruby code prior to running all the feature files in Cucumber? I tried to do that directly in the feature file (like `ap 'hi'`), but Cucumber seemed to ignore that and just proceeded to the scenario.

Comment: I think you're looking for a `Before` hook, which is like `setup` in `Test::Unit`.  This SO thread might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031096/cleanup-steps-for-cucumber-scenarios/15031582#15031582

Answer (score 0):

If you want code to be executed before all features/scenarios are ran you can use the AfterConfiguration hook

```
AfterConfiguration do
  #code you want ran
end
```

This hook is only executed once and after cucumber has finished setting up its environment.

If you want code just to run before all scenarios you can us the Before hook

```
Before do
  #code you want ran
#end
```

And if you are in a situation where you want the code to run only for certain scenarios you can utilize the tag functionality/filtering of the hooks

```
@my_scenario
Scenario: This is my scenario

Scenario: This is not my scenario
```

with the hook

```
Before('@my_scenario') do
   #code you want ran
end
```

The above hook will only run for the "This is my scenario" scenario.