# Cucumber 'Postground' tag to combine the steps which are same for all scenarios in a feature file

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Extending the question [Cleanup steps for Cucumber scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031096/cleanup-steps-for-cucumber-scenarios). I am aware that I can use tagged `@After` hooks to repeat the last few steps for all scenarios matching the tag. However, this implementation will be in my java classes and my business users will have no idea. Also my acceptance tests are huge, around 200. Lets say each feature file contains 10 scenarios and last 3-4 steps are common for all of them in that feature file. So i will have 20 feature file and 20 unique tags. I can create 20 `@After` hooks function and silently perform those steps. But how will my business owners know this if they cannot see these technical implementation?

The purpose of '`Background`' tag is to repeat the same steps at beginning of the scenarios. We could have easily achieved this by using tagged `@Before` hooks, then why Background tag? If we have new feature of having '`Postground`' tag, which is opposite of '`Background`' tag, above problem can be solved. What do you think?

Note: I have logged an [issue](https://github.com/cucumber/docs.cucumber.io/issues/452) for this, but it got closed by @aslakhellosoy. I think I did not articulate the problem statement well.

Comment: Can you add the steps you are repeating for each scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating the same steps one by one, you can extract helper methods to perform the individual actions those steps perform, and call those helper methods either one by one in individual steps, or in sequence from the overarching step. 
That way you can still make visible to the business users what happens, without having to spell out all the individual steps.

For more information, check the [Cucumber documentation on Helper Methods](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/step-organization/#helper-methods).
If you still have more questions (I realise the documentation on Helper Methods isn't very extensive), please join the [Cucumber Slack](https://cucumberbdd-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/).